# Spinner in ActionBar is not updating ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-holo-everywhere

I have two elements:

1. Spinner INSIDE THE ACTIONBAR (HoloEverywhere (support.v7)) of my Activity set with an `onItemSelectedListener()`.
2. Listview in my Activity which is filled with an ArrayAdapter

When I choose an Item  from the Spinner, the ListView should be updated. But somehow there is a problem with my Spinner I guess. The ListView first updates when I clicked in a TextField of my Activity after I choose a SpinnerItem.

My code:

```
// Get a databaseConnection and fills the history variable with the data of 
// the selected spinnerItem "history" is right filled with all Strings for 
// the chosen Spinner from the database -> works correct

public void updateHistory() {
    sqlLightDatabase database = new sqlLightDatabase(this);
    ArrayList<String> history = database.getArrayList(
                                    mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());


    // set the adapter to the ListView
    ArrayAdapter<String> listenAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                                  R.layout.list_item, history);
    myListView.setAdapter(listenAdapter);

    // the code works through, but the ListView is not shown the update 
    // instantly. But now, when I click a TextField in my Activity, myListView 
    // shows the new data
}

// Is instantly called when an Item is selected in mySpinner (in my ActionBar)

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) 
{
    // the updateHistory function is called but myLitstView doesn't get
    // updated with new Data

    updateHistory();

    //Just for testing. The following is working instantly fine.
    drivenDistance_TF.setText("History changed");
}
```

I tried the last two days to fix this issue, but I have absolute no idea what I could else try to get the ListView instantly updated.

There is no ErrorLog, because there are no errors.

Comment: Try to call myListView.invalidateViews() after setAdapter

Comment: Hey. Sorry, this is also not working.
What I found out is that this problem just occurs on older SDK's.

Answer (score 0):

You must call notifyDataSetChanged method to update data in list view

So write this line

```
listenAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after `myListView.setAdapter(listenAdapter);` 
in updateHistory();